# Converting time to milliseconds?

Tags: matlab

I have some time as **string** format in my data. Can anyone help me to convert this date to milliseconds in Matlab.

This is an example how date looks like `'00:26:16:926'`, So, that is 0 hours 26 minutes 16 seconds and 926 milliseconds. After converting this time, I need to get only milliseconds such as 1576926 milliseconds for the time that I gave above. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you try using [`datevec`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datevec.html) instead?  `datevec` is designed to take in various time and date strings and it parses the string and spits out useful information for you.  There's no need to use `regexp` or split up your string in any way.  Here's a quick example:

```
[~,~,~,hours,minutes,seconds] = datevec('00:26:16:926', 'HH:MM:SS:FFF');
out = 1000*(3600*hours + 60*minutes + seconds);

out = 

1576926
```

In this format, the output of `datevec` will be a 6 element vector which outputs the year, month, day, hours, minutes and seconds respectively.  The millisecond resolution will be added on to the sixth element of `datevec`'s output, so all you have to do is convert the fourth to sixth elements into milliseconds and add them all up, which is what is done above.  If you don't specify the actual day, it just defaults to January 1st of the current year... but we're not using the date anyway... we just want the time!

---

The beauty with `datevec` is that it can accept **multiple** strings so you're not just limited to a single input.  Simply put all of your strings into a single cell array, then use `datevec` in the following way:

```
times = {'00:26:16:926','00:27:16:926', '00:28:16:926'};
[~,~,~,hours,minutes,seconds] = datevec(times, 'HH:MM:SS:FFF');
out = 1000*(3600*hours + 60*minutes + seconds);

out =

    1576926
    1636926
    1696926
```

Comment: This is less flexible as strings like `0:26:19:926` would not be accepted. And it is not easier :) However, +1 for `datevec` - nice function!

Comment: @matheburg - I suppose not, but if each string follows the same format, then I don't see why we can't use it :)  Thanks for the upvote BTW!

Comment: Our answers are all quite similar, so I am desperately looking for the advantage in mine ;P

Comment: @matheburg - Hahah fair enough :) +1 for you too btw.

Comment: @matheburg - I have the additional advantage where you don't need to loop through strings.  `datevec` accepts a cell array of times and can compute the times in a vectorized manner.

Comment: @matheburg - Hehe :) well in all fairness you came up with your solution first!  I actually was sitting here for a while thinking of how to do it more efficiently.

Comment: How can apply this to an array whose all elements in same format like 0:26:19:926? When I try `[~,~,~,hours,minutes,seconds] = datevec('data.ESUTimestamp', 'HH:MM:SS:FFF');`, it give me error (Error using dtstr2dtvecmx) and (Error in datevec (line 118)). 
ESUTimestamp is an date column in my data file.

Comment: @Ram - Because you are putting your variable into a string by putting single quotes around it.  Remove the single quotes and try again. `[~,~,~,hours,minutes,seconds] = datevec(data.ESUTimestamp, 'HH:MM:SS:FFF');`

Comment: @rayryeng Stupid mistake :) Really thank you friend.

Comment: @rayryeng it is not only the time to answer that counts :)

Comment: @Ram - No problem :) My pleasure to help

Answer (score 5):

One solution could be:

```
timeString = '00:26:16:926';
cellfun(@(x)str2num(x),regexp(timeString,':','split'))*[3600000;60000;1000;1]
```

Result:

```
 1576926
```

Comment: Remark: `regexp(timeString,':','split')` can be replaced in current versions of Matlab by `strsplit(timeString,':')`

Comment: How Can I apply this to my data? When I tried to apply, I got some error ( Error using str2num (line 33)). Here is what I did 'timeString =data.ESUTimestamp; cellfun(@(x)str2num(x),regexp(timeString,':','split'))*[3600000;60000;1000;1]'

ESUTimestamp is the column in my data, and its all the elements are the same format as example I gave in my question.

Comment: Are you sure `data.ESUTimestamp` is a pure string? Or is it a cell array? In this case you could try something like: `yourCellData = data.ESUTimestamp; cellfun(@(timeString)cellfun(@(x)str2num(x),regexp(timeString,':','split'))*[3600000;60000;1000;1], yourCellData)` ... just a guess

Comment: Or you apply a loop if this is more convenient for you: `yourCellData = data.ESUTimestamp; for idx = 1:length(yourCellData), timeString = yourCellData{idx}; cellfun(@(x)str2num(x),regexp(timeString,':','split'))*[3600000;60000;1000;1], end`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your date string comes in that format consistently, you could use something as simple as this:

```
test = '00:26:16:926';
H = str2num(test(1:2)); % hours
M = str2num(test(4:5)); % minutes
S = str2num(test(7:8)); % seconds
MS = str2num(test(10:12)); % milliseconds
totalMS = MS + 1000*S + 1000*60*M + 1000*60*60*H;
```

Output:

```
1576926.00
```

Comment: So, Do I need to use for loop to apply this all the string date in my data?

Comment: If you wanted to do this process multiple times, then you could use a loop. But preferably, define a function that takes your time string as input and total ms as output, then use `cellfun` on your cell array of strings.

Answer (score -1):

you can convert a single string with a date or even a vector by using `datevec` for conversion and the dot product

```
a = ['00:26:16:926' ; '08:42:12:936']
datevec(a,'HH:MM:SS:FFF') * [0 0 0 3600e3 60e3 1e3]'

ans =

     1576926
    31332936
```

Comment: Don't see how this is any different from my answer, other than cleverly computing the sum using a dot product... not to mention that you answered this question almost 5 months after it was solved (by me).